# Link Button to a page not showing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have cloned the repo from https://github.com/lockitron/selfstarter and i am trying to create link to a new page in the header but the link doesn't show up

I want to create an "Explore" Button in the header so i created an explorer controller and model ran migration and used link_to helper method in header partial to create the new button linking to the page but it doesn show up .How do i show my "Explore" button which links to the 'show.html.erb page' in explorer folder

routes.rb

```
resources :explorer
```

explorer_controller

```
class ExplorerController < ApplicationController
    def show

end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<p> hello </p>
```

header.html.erb

```
<div id="header">
 <%= link_to 'Explore, explore_path %>


</div>
```

I am getting the following error too

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Preorder#index
Showing /Users/views/preorder/_header.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:controller=>"explorer", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #2):
1 <div id="header">
2  <%= link_to 'Explore', explorer_path %>
3 <div class="wrapper clearfix">
4 <h1 id="lockitron_header"><a href="/"><%= Settings.product_name %></a></h1>

Trace of template inclusion: views/layouts/application.html.erb

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/preorder/_header.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_preorder__header_html_erb___3778671432332580621_70190937023480'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___270280154590328587_70190919949800'
```

Comment: Is that a typo or are you really missing a closing `'` in :
<%= link_to 'Explore, explore %>

Comment: In addition, are you rendering `header.html.erb` in your application layout?

Comment: rb512 I was missing the comma and i added it .JTG i am rendering the header.html.erb in application layout.I still cant see the button and i get an error for missing required key too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both issues have the same cause. But before getting to that, I'd like to point out some things about resources in Rails. As [the documentation shows](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), you can either have a [plural](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) or [singular](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) resource.

I'm not able to determine whether your explorer resource needs to be singular or plural, but let's assume there can only be a single explorer in your application. That would mean you have a singular resource, which is defined as follows in your `routes.rb`:

```
resource :explorer
```

Rails will now assume the controller is named after the plural form, explorers. Open up a terminal and run `rake routes`. You will see all the available paths and the controller the route maps to.

Your controller will be located at `app/controllers/explorers_controller.rb`, and look like this:

```
class ExplorersController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end
end
```

Back to your issue. The `_header` partial isn't able to render to due the error:

> No route matches {:controller=>"explorer", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]

What this error says is that you need to provide an `Explorer` record (or its ID) in the path so that Rails knows which explorer to link to. This, however, is only true in case of plural resources.

In case of a singular resource, you don't need to provide its ID, since there can only be one! So your view will work the way it is, if you've adjusted your routes and controller like I explained.

Comment: I changed resources to resource and the errors disappeard